# Jquery Ajax loading image while getting the data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a Jquery Ajax function to fetch the data from database, on click event.

This function works fine and displays the data.
But it takes time to load the data, so I want to put a loading image, while the data is been fetched. 
I used this method to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#imgs").hide();
            $(".letter").bind('click', function(){
                $("#imgs").fadeIn();
                var val = $(".letter").val;
                var site = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
                $.ajax({
                    url: site+'/wp-content/themes/premiumnews/newContent.php?letter='+$(this).html(), 
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#imgs").hide();
                        $("#content1").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the button, the loading image appears, but after success the image should disappear, in my case it still remains there

Is my code wrong? or I have used a wrong method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I have always used in the past:

```
$('#loading_div').hide().ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just before your $.ajax(); call do this.  Replace the entire html with this before the ajax call.  Then onsuccess the entire html is replaced with your content.

```
$("#content1").html("<img style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Loading...\" title=\"Loading...\" />");
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you code looks fine. Are you sure that the success function is being called? Try adding `alert("")` to the success function and see if it is successfully being called. If not there in lies your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#report").live( "submit" , function(){
    // Add loading image until get the results
    $("#loading_div").html("<img style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Loading...\" title=\"Loading...\" />"); 

    var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Get 
    $.post( "ajax_report.php", formdata, function( data ) {
    $("#results").html ( data ); // Add success data in '#results' element
    $("#loading_div").empty(); // Remove loading image on success
        });

        return false;
});
```

Add these lines in your page.

```
<span id="loading_div"></span>
<span id="results"></span>
<form id="report" name="report" action="" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" value=""></input>
    <input name="middlename" value=""></input>
    <input name="lastname" value=""></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.