# How To Call Function on page Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, loading

I'm Using Web service using AJAX Call In My HTML Page  . Web Service Returning Data Nearly 30 to 40 second's .

During This Loading Time I Need to Use Some Loading Gif Images After Data Completely Received  Form Web Service The Loading Image Must Be Hide.

I'm Using Only HTML,JAVASCRIPT,CSS,J Query.

Any Idea Or Samples Needed.

I'm Using Following Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.write('<img src="http://www.esta.org.uk/spinner.gif">');
});
$( window ).load(function() {
//This following Function Related To My Design
jQuery(".chosen").data("placeholder", "Select Frameworks...").chosen();
var config = {
'.chosen-select': {},
'.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
'.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
'.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
'.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
}
for (var selector in config) {
$(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
});
```

In The Above Code My Problem Is On Page Load Gif Image Show But It's Not Hide Only Gif Image Only Showing.

Comment: Any code outside of a domcontentready (ie jquery ready) listener will execute as soon as your script is loaded. What are you trying to do?

Comment: as simple as it can be...add a div with loading image hide it first... show it before ajax call was made..and hide it again inside ajax callback... **with no posted  codes or atleast things you have tried..i can only give you such answer ...which i doubt is useful but yes same goes for us... with no related codes the question itself is useless to us.**

Comment: Are you using `$.ajax()` to get the results? If so, look for the `beforeSend` property.

Comment: @bipen i Add My Code Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a hidden image on your page and as soon as your ajax call is made, make that image visible

```
$('#image').show();
$.ajax({
   complete: function(){
    $('#image').hide();
  }
});
```

and hide that image again on Complete of Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Use your ajax request callback (on success/failure) instead of page load.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the request just show a gif animation by setting the Display to block
then when you have the data set the display to none
or use jquery

```
function showHourGlass()
{
  $("#gifimage").show();
}

function hideHourGlass()
{
  $("#gifimage").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for ideas, I have one sample -
http://www.myntra.com/shoes
load scroll down fastly this is the ajax jquery request which is exact output which you have mentioned in your question

Check source code

[Jquery Ajax loading image while getting the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612308/jquery-ajax-loading-image-while-getting-the-data)

This what the html looks like:

```
<button id="save">Load User</button>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    // add loading image to div
    $('#loading').html('<img src="http://preloaders.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');

    // run ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom",
        success: function (d) {
            // replace div's content with returned data
            // $('#loading').html('<img src="'+d.avatar_url+'"><br>'+d.login);
            // setTimeout added to show loading
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#loading').html('<img src="' + d.avatar_url + '"><br>' + d.login);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this will help you.